# Adjusting zoom levels in leaflet js removes all layers and prevents any further zoom functionality in IE11

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, leaflet

So I have a Ruby on Rails app that uses Leaflet JS to display a rather large map file overlaid with various layers of boxes, markers, paths, etc. However, if I load the map through IE 11, once I change zoom levels from the initial value everything is removed, the map stops loading, and I can no longer change zoom levels. I do not believe it is a problem with my code for several reasons, mainly the facts that:

- Everything works in Firefox and Chrome
- Map works on IE version 9
- Code produces no error messages in console or anywhere else

So I have to admit I'm at a near-complete loss as to the cause of this error. I've pulled the latest stable leaflet release but it didn't change anything. I'm hoping someone has a suggestion that might help out.

Comment: Kind of hard to help you with this without a testcase. I'de suggest scaling your entire setup down and reducing it to a simple testcase untill you can easily replicate the problem. It could very wel be tied to just one type of layer. Start with just one tile layer and a layergroup with just a few markers go from there.

Comment: Heh. I'm actually in the middle of doing that myself. I'm aware it's not much information to go off of which is why I'm having trouble debugging it myself tbh. Was hoping someone somewhere had had a similar problem.

Comment: You can always lookup the known issues with Leaflet in the issuetracker on Github: [https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues) I've skimmed over them for you, found nothing. Good luck with the debugging.